# Required depends on radio button

Tags: php, symfony

I try to have a required value depends on radio button

```
$builder
            ->add('radio',ChoiceType::class,[
                'label' => 'My radio button',
                'choices'=>[
                    'Yes'=>'Yes',
                    "No"=>"No"
                ],
                "expanded"=>true,
                "multiple"=>false,
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => false
            ])
            ->add('file input', FileInputType::class, [
                'label' => 'put your file',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true or false // depends on radio button
            ])
```

But i can't find how to do this, i'm a beginner in symfony.
I use Symfony 5

Please if you have an idea i'm listening

Comment: Seems like you want to make the 'file input' field required or not, based on the value of the 'radio' field, right?

Comment: Yes exactly @WahyuKristianto :)

Comment: You can use JS to handle the change event on the radio buttons and set the 'required' attribute for the 'file input' field accordingly

Comment: In pure PHP, you cannot dynamically change the required attribute based on a radio button's value without reloading the page because PHP runs on the server-side, while this kind of interactivity requires client-side code (like JavaScript).

Comment: Or you can handle this on the server-side by validating the form after submission. If the radio button has a specific value (e.g., 'Yes'), you can then check if the file input is empty and return an error message accordingly.

Comment: oh i got stuck on doing it in php while a little addeventlistener in javascript and it's done... thanks :)

Comment: Nice! I try to answer too

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps you have to implement to achieve this feature.

1. Implement form events `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` and `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`.
2. `PRE_SET_DATA` is used for rendering form with existing data. For example: If Radio YES then display the file_input field otherwise another field is rendered in form.
3. `PRE_SUBMIT` is used for set field value based on Radio input. You can add logic here. For example: If YES, then set file_input field value.
4. Implement javascript code onChange event on the Radio field and handle show/hide events on other fields.

*Note*: In Symfont form, If you change anything from the js side then it will not work when the form is submitted. That's why we have to handle the same logic via `FORM EVENTS`

Comment: thanks but i will do it in pure JS it's more simple for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to handle the change event on the radio buttons and set `required` attribute for the 'file input' field accordingly.

```php
$builder
    ->add('radio', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label' => 'My radio button',
        'choices' => [
            'Yes' => 'Yes',
            'No' => 'No'
        ],
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'placeholder' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'id' => 'radio_choice'
        ]
    ])
    ->add('file_input', FileType::class, [
        'label' => 'Put your file',
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false, // Initially set to false
        'attr' => [
            'id' => 'file_input'
        ]
    ]);
```

```js
// main.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#radio_choice input[type=radio]');
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file_input');

    function updateFileInputRequired() {
        // Set the 'required' attribute based on the selected radio button value
        fileInput.required = [...radioButtons].some(radio => radio.checked && radio.value === 'Yes');
    }

    // Add a change event listener for each radio button
    radioButtons.forEach(radio => {
        radio.addEventListener('change', updateFileInputRequired);
    });

    // Update the 'required' attribute when the page loads
    updateFileInputRequired();
});
```